# fiql syntax for fetching null value data

Tags: java, web-applications, jax-rs, cxf, cxfrs

We are using **[fiql](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-search.html)** for data filtering. My requirement is to fetch data where a particular column value is null using **[fiql](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-search.html)** tried different ways but not getting the required result.

My requirement is to fetch record from a table where a particular column data is null but unable to set fiql condition for eg. 
mobNo=='NULL' or mobNo==NULL but its not working

I have not given code because fiql is working absolutely fine in other scenarios just not getting right syntax to give condition for NULL data.

Given [**fiql**](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-search.html) link in case you need reference on fiql

Comment: We are using MySql database

Comment: Hey, can you share what you have done (code, queries, etc.) and where it seems to you that it is not working. That will enable people here to help you

Comment: am simply sending a get request with fiql but when i am trying to fetch the field where data is null it is not returning proper data